# How to use git LFS repo as submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-lfs

I'm actually using git lfs to track some binary files I need in my project.
I have one repo dedicated to these files, and an another main repo with all of my source code.
I added the git lfs repo in my main repo as a submodule.

My problem is that now when I clone my main repo, and I run `git submodule update --init`, the command is really slow, and take a long time to download all my binaries. Why not, but it seems the main repo contains also binaris in `.git/modules/path/to/submodules`.

How can i avoid thay and only have my binary files in the dedicated submodule ?

Thanks !